# Trying to install Wine in Ubuntu 12.10, get dependencies error

Tags: ubuntu, wine, ubuntu-12.10

I have looked everywhere for some help, maybe it will be impossible to install Wine on Ubuntu 64-bit until an update is released.

When I try to install I get the following errors

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but 1.16.7ubuntu6 is to be installed
         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu20 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-amd64 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1) but 1.4.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4.1-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
```

Anyone has a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why -1.  This is a legit question with no answers anywhere else.

I managed to fix this and a lot of other dependency issues (like Skype) by adding i386 architecture.

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Awesome, this worked like a charm and this was the only place I could find this answer.  Thanks!